# I will make make my introduction short

Tags: grammar, translation

Does「自己紹介を短いようにする」mean "I will make my introduction short".

I want to say "I can only speak a little Japanese, so I'll make my introduction short".

「日本語が少ししか話せないので、自己紹介を短いようにする。」

I'm not sure what the effect of 「ように」is. Or is it alright to just say 「短くする」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 日本語が少ししか話せないので、自己紹介を**短いように**する。

This is weird and unnatural to my ears.

> 日本語が少ししか話せないので、自己紹介を**短く**する。

This is perfect.

> 日本語が少ししか話せないので、自己紹介を**長くならないように**する。

This is perfect, too.